# geojson postgis ST_DWithin ST_AsGeoJSON

Tags: postgis, geojson

Can anyone help me how to convert to geojson the result of the query from ST_DWithin (objects within a certain radius)? im lost how to use ST_AsGeoJSON.

Comment: What have you tried? There are examples [in the manual](http://postgis.net/documentation).

Comment: I tried this one:
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(geocolumn) FROM geotable WHERE ST_DWithin(geocolumn, 'POINT(1000 1000)', 100.0);

but the result is a list of geojsons, is there a way to combine all those geojsons into one? thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use an aggregate function like [`ST_Collect`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Collect.html) to group the geometries:

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Collect(geocolumn))
FROM geotable
WHERE ST_DWithin(geocolumn, 'POINT(1000 1000)', 100.0);
```

The result will either be a MULTI- geometry, or GEOMETRYCOLLECTION.